# Need guidance or ideas on database design for Web Page Select drop down boxes

Tags: ajax, combobox, dojo, business-process-management

I'm working with the IBM BPM application, which is essentially building web pages that users interact with. I have (dojo) combo select boxes where they select options from a dropdown list. The choices are being populated from ajax calls to the server which basically return a list of name/value pairs or strings. I created a database to store the choices, but I could not find a good example of the best way to design a table to store values like this. It works good for drop down options that are not related. I have columns for "option group", "option name", "option value", which lets me store groups of options for each dropdown.

The issue we're running into with this design now is what happens when you have 3 dropdowns, each dependent on the previous selection. Option 1 is populated fine from this table, then when you choose a value, it's used to query the table for Option 2 choices. It starts to grow exponentially when a new Option 3 is added, because you have to add a row for each Option 2 choice also.

I'm also wondering if using a database is really the best solution for this or if we should be using external files somehow. I would say that the options are not actually going to change that often, but I also do not want to have to redeploy code or files just to add a new choice for users to choose.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursion) to iterate a parent child design. In the database, you could add a column for `parentId` which maps to the `id` for its parent. At the root node level the parentId will equal 0. Then you can run a recursive method to navigate your 'tree structure' from database. Below is a rudimentary recursive method that might provide insight.

```
private void myTest(int optionId, List<Option> optionList) {
        OptionAction optionAction = new OptionAction(); // access DAO to retrieve options
        Option option = optionAction.getOption(optionId);
        if (option.getParentId() == 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            optionList.add(option);
            myTest(option.getParentId(), optionList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about table design where there really isn't a parent/child relationship? Most of my values in the table are for standalone drop downs. It's just a few exceptions that have the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Logan, the previous answer is a good one, but to answer your follow-up comment/question:  You can set up the parentId column is nullable meaning "can be null".  So you can have a single data-store to house the object definitions you need to service both kinds of uses.  You can probably do all this in a single table, keeping it self-contained and simple.  How you write the code that MANAGES the contents of the table is another thing, but shouldn't pose any big issues.  Good luck :)